# SalesForce integration - notify external system on SF object definition change

Tags: caching, notifications, salesforce, integration

We have a software that is integrated with SalesForce using SF SOAP API. As we are sending/receiving data to/from SF on user level, we must know which SF objects and object fields is user allowed to access (based on SF visibility rules). Therefore, we first invoke describeSObject(objName) and store it to our cache to speed up integration.

What happens is, when our clients change visibility rules or rename object fields on SF side, they must invalidate cache in our application. If they forget to do that (and they usually do), we are not aware that our cache is invalid.

Question: is there a way to invoke our web service from SF when visibility rules changes, or object field is added/deleted/renamed? If that is possible, as visibility rules in SF are quite complex, how can we differ which users are affected by change (so we do not invalidate cache for everyone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you can't currently.

As an alternative, catch the exceptions that occur due to the metadata mismatch and flush the local cache for that user. Then retry the original request with the updated metadata.

Comment: Hm, that way I can not know if object SF definition has really changed or I simply have wrong mapping or invalid SF query (our clients can write their own queries to SF). I can not clear cache every time - that guarantees bad performance only.

Comment: I'm not saying to clear the cache every time. Only when the exception that comes back from the query indicates your meta data is out of date for the user. I.e. They requested a field that no longer exists. I don't think there is another way of detecting schema changes short of polling the meta data.

Comment: "I suspect you can't currently." - looks like correct answer at this moment. There is no way to subscribe to meta data changes.