# Salesforce – Notify external API (or create activity event) on custom object change

Tags: salesforce

I need a fairly trivial thing: every time a user changes a salesoforce custom object field, I need to notify the external service about the change.

Either push the notification or somehow log the object change event somewhere in salesforce. (and make the external service regularly check those latest events for any new activity)

Is either of those options possible?

The only info I could find on this issue is [this somewhat relevant SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676681/salesforce-integration-notify-external-system-on-sf-object-definition-change), but it's 3 years old and doesn't answer anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by creating a [PushTopic](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API#PushTopic) and subscribing to it via [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API).